# processResources task in gradle doesn't copy a file

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

While processing resources in a gradle build, is it possible to copy certain special resources to a target directory?

```
processResources {
  println "Project Dir :  $projectDir"
   copy {
      from ('${projectDir}/../../../project-abc/src/main/resources/SkipColumns.properties')
      into ('${projectDir}/target/classes/META-INF/project-abc')
    }
  }
```

> gradle processResources
>   When I run above command, the build is successful. But it doesn't copy SkipColumns file.

Comment: Try to use `dependsOn` or `doLast/doFirst`. `processResources.dependsOn copy {...}` or `processResources.doLast copy {...}`.

Answer (score 0):

Removing parentheses worked.

```
copy {
    from ("$projectDir/../../../project-abc/src/main/resources/SkipColumns.properties")
    into ("$projectDir/target/classes/META-INF/project-abc")
  }
```